# Grouping exported types by name

Tags: go

I have this in a file:

```
import (
    "huru/routes/login"
    "huru/routes/nearby"
    "huru/routes/person"
    "huru/routes/register"
    "huru/routes/share"
)

// Handlers
type RegisterHandler = register.Handler
type LoginHandler = login.Handler
type NearbyHandler = nearby.Handler
type ShareHandler = share.Handler
type PersonHandler = person.Handler
```

this works, but I am wondering if there is a way to group them, like so:

```
// PSEUDO CODE 
var Handlers = {
 Register : register.Handler
 Login : login.Handler
 Nearby : nearby.Handler
 Share : share.Handler
 Person : person.Handler
}
```

note yes that's bogus syntax but hopefully you know what I mean. What I am trying to do is export a namespace, so I can do this:

```
import (
  "huru/x"
)

x.Handlers.Register{}
```

instead of:

```
x.RegisterHandler{}
```

Comment: ah, good to know, why won't that compile by the way?

Comment: If that won't compile, what I want to do will probably never work

Comment: I am just trying to group structs declarations into one namespace

Comment: Please stop abusing type aliases.

Comment: @Volker someone tell Golang to adopt namespaces or something, this is not good as is

Comment: Go's namespaces are packages and they work fine.

Comment: ughhh no they dont work completely, but whatevs

Answer (score 0):

Could you make Handlers.Register a function instead? Then you could register them to a global map or something.

Comment: I could, but I ultimately in this case I want to share types, so that the type info can be shared